# Webpack and webcomponent work together

Tags: webpack, web-component

I am using webcomponents for a project now and running into problems loading them through webpack. Any idea whether these two can work together?

Comment: Can you provide more information? How is it failing?

Comment: Tks for the reply. How can I load webcomponents-lite.min.js through webpack?

Comment: I found this thread, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/547 . Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a [simple boilerplate](https://github.com/vardius/web-components-webpack-es6-boilerplate) webpack2 project for web components. Hello world example with template. You can easy add polymer to it if needed.

I created this project bootstrap for my needs, as I do not use polymer it is not included in my boilerplate. However I am sure there is no problem to include it in project.